# Put a StringBuffer in a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, character-encoding, bytebuffer

I am trying to put a string buffer in a bytebuffer..

```
out.put(ss);
```

where out is a ByteBuffer and ss is a StringBuffer. Is there any easy way to do this? Assuming ASCII encoding for the string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringBuffer buf = ...;
byte[] bytes = buf.toString().getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

or possibly `"ISO-8859-1"`

Comment: Does this pollute the `String` space in Java?  I've heard that this can be bad for memory reasons; by calling "toString" on large bytebuffers (many MB) we cause these strings to live forever in the JVM.  Am I making this up?  Is there anyway to go straight from StringBuffer to Bytes?